# I am trying to assign values to the vectors, I tried for loop, but it is not working?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have this huge data vector "a"
here is a screenshot

[image]

Now I am supposed to find inconsistencies with the gene data. Basically... a positive number is given 1, 0 is given 0, and a negative is given -1. I am trying to make a command that would do something like this:

```
if a > 0, then print 1.. a < 0, print -1... a = 0, print 0.
```

I would also like it to be in a vector fashion like the image above in 1s, 0s and -1s.

I tried the for loop, if statement but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: The `ifelse` function operates on vectors, and would work for more general problems like this.  @RHertel's answer is perfect for your particular use case, though.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this helps:

```
b <- sign(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# create some data for illustration
a <- rnorm(100, 0, 56)
print_a<-ifelse(x>0, 1, ifelse(x==0, 0, -1))
print_a
```

Comment: Greeting from the VLQ "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." Might you consider adding a bit of explanation?

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @Rhertel's answer as a quick way to accomplish the task.

However, if you wish to fix your for loop, please post your code. Here is a general example of a for loop implementing what you wanted to do using the iris dataset.

```
library(datasets)
for (i in diff(iris[,1])){
  if (i < 0){print(-1)}
  else if (i > 0){print(1)}
  else {print(0)}
}
```